# Remove Trailing Slash from Magento URL

Tags: magento, url-rewriting

I understand there are many answered questions on this particular issue but I haven't found anything specific to Magento, and I was wondering if changing the .htaccess file will have repercussions in my Magento store.

Basically I have links in my navigation that go straight to a filtered category page so they look as follows..

```
Example.com/hairproducts.html?manufacturer=412
```

However when I click these links they end up navigating to the URL with a trailing slash...

```
Example.com/hairproducts.html?manufacturer=412/
```

which then ignores the filter and takes them to the category page.

Cheers for any help.

Comment: Can you give me your code where this URL generates ? If its simple then you can use $url = rtrim($url, '/');

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I assume you have the urls generated in a phtml file like this:

```
<?php echo $this->getUrl('hairproducts.html?manufacturer=412'); ?>
```

or in a block/page content like this

```
 {{store url="hairproducts.html?manufacturer=412"}}
```

Change them to this:
In a phtml file:

```
<?php echo $this->getUrl('', array('_direct'=>'hairproducts.html', '_query'=>'manufacturer=412'); ?>
```

or in a block/page content

```
 {{store _direct="hairproducts.html" _query="manufacturer=412"}}
```

If I assumed wrong then post the way you are generating the urls.

Comment: That worked a treat, I was calling them in a block as per your second suggestion.
Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @marius. Worked like a charm for me.

Comment: @marius what if we are using block file returning controller path with some querystring values. For example return $this->getUrl('namespace/controller/filename?values=' . $value1);

Comment: `<?php echo $this->getUrl('namespace/controller/filename', array('_query'=>'manufacturer=412'); ?>`